# Cocos studio CustomParticleWidget cause other widget invisible

Tags: cocos2d-x

UI add a `CustomParticleWidget` in cocos studio and it behaves normal, but when export the json file to the game all the widget in the same json file become invisible, including buttons and imageviews.

Any one have ideas about this?

Comment: Unclear. Need more information. Post what code you have tired and what error you are getting?

Comment: no error in code, it seems with CustomParticleWidget, other widget render not right.